# Web socket autobanh test suit implementation

Tags: python, go, websocket, autobahn

Title:
Implementing Autobahn Test Suite for WebSocket Server at ws://localhost:8080/demo

Question:

I am attempting to implement the Autobahn Test Suite to thoroughly test my WebSocket server running at ws://localhost:8080/demo. However, I have been unable to find sufficient documentation to guide me through the process. The repository I have found related to Autobahn Test Suite is available here: https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-testsuite.

Comment: This question needs more focus. Try to identify one issue that you are struggling with and ask a specific question about that. Have you tried anything at all? The question is tagged with both "go" and "python".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: See [Testing WebSocket server implementations](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-testsuite#testing-websocket-server-implementations). To use the default fuzzing client configuration, run your websocket endpoint at ws://localhost:9001.  The test endpoint should read messages from the peer and echo those message back to the peer.

Comment: Can please explain in details